# Flex - Call JavaScript Function And Open a Popup Window that Displays Data

Tags: javascript, html, flash, apache-flex, externalinterface

I have been stuck trying to figure this out...

I have a Flex (Flash) App, and I am called a JavaScript function and passing in data:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available)
ExternalInterface.call("jsFunctionToCalled", passingSomeData);
```

In my index.template.html file, I have created the JS function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function jsFunctionToCalled(value) {
window.alert(value);
}
</script>
```

When I click a Button component in Flex, that JS alert window pops up. That works fine; However, I would like to open up a browser window, where I can access the "File/Print" option. I need to open this new browser window and parse the data from the value object. The value object is a String of HTML formatted data. So I need to display that data on the new popup window. I was thinking maybe I need to do something like this, which someone posted somewhere, but nothing pops up. I also tried window.opener and nothing pops up. If I provide a URL, it opens the URL fine, but I do not want to open a URL, I want to open a new window that I can print, and populate the window with the HTML data.

```
<script>
function openWin()
{
myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
myWindow.document.write("This is 'myWindow'!");
myWindow.focus();
myWindow.opener.document.write("<p>This is the source window!</p>");
}
</script>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am trying to figure a way to be able to print, without saving the file first (CRAPPY FLASH), and I do not have a web server to save my file to, in order to avoid saving the file first.

Thanks

Comment: did you check the popup blocker blocked it? did it work without invoking by the flash function?

Comment: @fmodos Unfortunately I did. I turned the popup blocker off and tried it in IE and in Firefox.

Comment: try to open this window without the flash integration, I mean create a simple html button and invoke the openWin

Comment: @fmodos Opening a window with this URL works, with the integration in Flash. But I need to open a new blank window (like a new panel) that populates that new window with some data passed in. I can only open a window in (Flex) Flash when I provide a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out and thought I would share it for anyone else experiencing this problem:

In my Flex Code:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available)
            {
                try
                {
                    ExternalInterface.call("onPrintRequest", dataToPass);
                }
                catch (error:SecurityError)
                {
                    Alert.show("Printing Security Error");
                }
                catch (error:Error)
                {
                    Alert.show("Printing Error");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Alert.show("Printing currently unavailable");
            }
```

In my index.template.html I added this JS method:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function onPrintRequest(value) {
                var w = window.open("about:blank");
                w.document.write(value);
                w.document.close();
                w.focus();
                w.print();
            }
        </script>
```

Works like a charm!!!

Answer (score 0):

The above changes works perfectly....

One addition - if you want to automatically close the new window after printing add the w.close() in the script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function onPrintRequest(value) {
            var w = window.open("about:blank");
            w.document.write(value);
            w.document.close();
            w.focus();
            w.print();
            w.close();
        }
</script>
```